# How to open Zxing project in Android Studio and compile it?

Tags: java, android-studio, barcode, zxing, qr-code

I downloaded the [Zxing project](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) and I'd like to open it in Android Studio and compile it.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Java library module:

[image]

Copy Zxing source code to this folder:

[image]

Ctrl+Shift+F9 to build this module.

Select your main project and press F4 to open project structure. Click dependencies and add the Zxing module:

[image]

Now you can use Zxing Classes and build your Android project.

Comment: I already tried that but, I don't see the CaptureActivity.java class which I'd like to edit before compiling. Any chance you can see the CaptureActivity class in your project structure please?

Comment: This is my own project. I didn't import the Android project provided by Zxing. I only used the core part (zxing\core\src\main\java\com\google\zxing). The CaptureActivity.java is located at zxing\android\src\com\google\zxing\client\android\.

Comment: Yes, thank you, but my purpose is to edit the CaptureActivity.java and recompile it within my main project. What do you suggest?

Comment: If so, you just need to import the source code. If you don't want to create a new module for Zxing, you need to build it independently to a jar file and add it to your project. Otherwise, the CaptureActivity cannot find some dependencies.

Comment: I'm looking my way through what you said, but in vain. Can you please help me with further details or steps? Thank you.

Comment: I opened independently the project containing the CaptureActivity class, but it can't find some dependancy. Could you please tell me how to build it independently to a jar file as you said?

Comment: Click New->New module, and then copy and paste the source code to the module folder. Build the source code to generate a jar file. You can read the post - [Time to Migrate Android Projects to Android Studio](http://www.codepool.biz/migrate-projects-to-android-studio.html)

Comment: Yes I tried that, but as you said, some dependencies are missing.

Comment: To be clear, this is the source code I wish to customize then rebuild : https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/master/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android
But when I open it in a new module independently, I get messages saying indepencies missing, like for instance : 
Error:(26, 24) error: cannot find symbol class PlanarYUVLuminanceSource